# Google Apps Script - Linking Google Calender and Google Sheets Not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to link a google sheets to a google calendar so that events are automatically created in the calendar from the information in the spreadsheet, I was following a video tutorial and I believe I followed all the steps correctly however the program did not work. I am very new to google apps script and programming in general, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QNFB.png)

[image]

[script editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQme6.png)

New Code

```java
function createMyCalenderEvent() {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(c_ee8f73580f686726516aaafb96f5ff9ec59582d10b9e07e314bc65e32fb20336@group.calendar.google.com
);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");
  const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  let idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => idx[h] = i);
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!r[idx["Created"]]) {
      let s = new Date(r[idx["Date of Event | "]]);
      let e = new Date(r[idx["Date of Event | "]]);
      e.setHours(s.getHours() + 1)
      cal.createEvent(r[idx["Organization Name | "]], s, e);
      sh.getRange(i + 2, idx["Created"] + 1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping the last two parameters in call to createEvent with `new Date()` like this `createEvent(entry[1], new Date(entry[4], new Date(entry[4]));``

Comment: Your starttime and endtime will be exactly the same.

Comment: Cooper, thank you, that seems to have solved part of the problem. However, now it is marking the semi-colon at the of `createEvent(entry[1], new Date(entry[4], new Date(entry[4]));`` as an error and is delivering the message, 'Error Attempted to execute createCalenderEvent, but could not save." when I try to run it.

Comment: Then you have a syntax error in your code.  I will need to see your current code. Exactly as it is written now.

Comment: Please post the latest code in your question at the end.  Learn to [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I have added the latest code to the end of my question.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis fr the second parameter of the createEvent method. You have to look very carefully at code.  Any small syntax error can keep the editor from saving your project

Comment: Syntax is now fixed, however now is it delivering the message, 'Exception: The parameters (String,(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent."

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function createMyCalenderEvent() {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(gobj.globals.calendarid);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  let idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => idx[h] = i);
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!r[idx["Created"]]) {
      let s = new Date(r[idx["Start"]]);
      let e = new Date(r[idx["Start"]]);
      e.setHours(s.getHours() + 1)
      cal.createEvent(r[idx["Name"]], s, e);
      sh.getRange(i + 2, idx["Created"] + 1).setValue(new Date());
    }
  });
}
```

Sheet0:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Name |  |  | Start | Created |
| 2 |  | Name1 |  |  | 8/13/2023 8:43:08 |  |
| 3 |  | Name2 |  |  | 8/13/2023 8:43:08 |  |

Sheet0 after creating events

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Name |  |  | Start | Created |
| 2 |  | Name1 |  |  | 8/13/2023 9:00:03 | 8/13/2023 8:57:51 |
| 3 |  | Name2 |  |  | 8/13/2023 9:00:03 | 8/13/2023 8:57:51 |

The Events in Calendar:

[image]

Comment: Execution Log delivered, 'Error   Attempted to execute createMyCalenderEvent, but could not save." when I tried to run it. I've added the current code to the end of my question.

Comment: Scratch that I forgot parathesis exist, the program works now thanks you so much for the help.